# How would I dump files from an APK?

Tags: android, dll, decompiling

I was looking to mod a game as I really felt like adding a few extra things. It is a mobile game so I got the APK and moved it onto my computer, and began to decompile it. I know it uses the Unity engile so I looked for the .dll files but I couldn't find them, so after reading I found out that they only appear during running the game so I have to dump the files. The problem is, I have no idea how to dump files from an APK. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a rooted device, and extract all the files you need in runtime.